# Get user by id from different tables

Tags: sql

I have a twitter lookalike site for studying purpose, where you can follow users.
Now I want tho fetch all the users that follow the logged in person.

The following table has three rows. id, user_id, follow_id

Now if user 1 whats to follow user 2. 
the values in the rows would be `user_id = 1` ,  `follow_id= 2`

But when I'm trying to fetch the users that have the same follow_id, i get only the user_id 2 in return. And not all the users that have follow_id=2

Any idea ?

```
SELECT 
    user.id, user.username, user.email,
    userdetails.profile_img, following.follow_id 
FROM 
    user 
JOIN 
    userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id 
JOIN 
    following on user.id = following.follow_id 
WHERE 
    following.follow_id = 2
```

This is how my table looks like

```
Following
id | user_id | follow_id

Tweets
user_id|id|date|message

user
id|email|password|username

userdetails
id|firstname|lastname|profile_img|user_id|about
```

Any tips ?

Comment: in which table you have both of the column `userid` and `followId` ?

Comment: @Sachin I updated my question with the table.

Comment: What's the problem with the query you have?

Comment: @DanBracuk It gives me the username of the user that's being followed, and not the users that are following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `JOIN following on user.id = following.follow_id` with `JOIN following on user.id = following.user_id`.

```
SELECT 
    user.id, user.username, user.email,
    userdetails.profile_img, following.follow_id 
FROM 
    user 
JOIN 
    userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id 
JOIN 
    following on user.id = following.user_id 
WHERE 
    following.follow_id = 2
```

Comment: I am almost sure that i tried that. haha, been stuck for a while. well work now!. thank you so much my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM Following 
INNER JOIN Users on Following.UserId=Users.Id
INNER JOIN UsersDetails on Users.Id=UserDetails.UserId
where Following.Follow_id=@UserId
```

of-course you can select column as you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user.id, user.username,user.email,
userdetails.profile_img, following.follow_id FROM user JOIN userdetails 
ON user.id = userdetails.user_id JOIN following 
ON user.id = following.follow_id WHERE following.follow_id = 2
```

To get all the ids of users that are matched to `follow_id` = 2:

```
SELECT user_id from following where follow_id = 2;
```

(I would change them name of `user_id` column in following table to `follower_id`)

To also get data off userdetails table associated with `user_id`:

```
SELECT userdetails.*, user.* FROM userdetails JOIN users 
ON user.id = userdetails.user_id JOIN following
ON user.id = following.***user_id*** WHERE following.follow_id = 2;
```

See if that works, I think your problem was that you joined following. `follow_id` to user instead of `following.user_id`